# Is there a functional difference between using parameterized query vs string interpolation?

Tags: python, sql, datetime

I'm working with a py2 codebase that performs the following query:

```
import datetime
# conn is a connector pointing to the sql database
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from table_name where end >= :start and end <= :end',
        { 'start' : datetime.datetime.combine(date, datetime.time(0)), # date is a datetime.date object
          'end' : datetime.datetime.combine(date, datetime.time(23,59,59)) })
```

Note the `end` column has integer format `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS`. This snippet uses parameterized querying and returns the correct rows. I was surprised that this works because I don't know how sql compares `YYYYMMDDHHMMSS` to a python datetime object. I assume implicit conversions occurs on the sql side.

I tried to change the query to use string interpolation:

```
import datetime
# conn is a connector pointing to the sql database
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('select * from table_name where end >= '%s' and end <= '%s' 
% (
   datetime.datetime.combine(date, dt.time(0)), 
   datetime.datetime.combine(date, dt.time(23,59,59)))
))
```

but this produces no results. Aren't these 2 execution queries identical?

Comment: What is the class of `conn` and `cursor`? Which library or module are they from? The documentation of `cursor.execute(...)` will probably explain that the parameterized query converts Python objects like datetime into strings suitable for the SQL query.

Comment: *"I tried to change the query to use string interpolation"*: why go for an approach that is known for its SQL injection vulnerability? As to why it is different: certainly those date objects will be converted to strings, and so you are suddenly doing a text based comparison, which all depends on how dates have been stringified. I wouldn't look further into this though, as it is an inferior solution.

Comment: I am surprised the code you have written didn’t even produce a syntax error.

Comment: @nitsas ah I see. It appears the connector is for sqlite3 (I know little about SQL). I just looked at the documentation in https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute and I don't see where it mentions any conversions?

Comment: @trincot I'm really not familiar with SQL. In this case, I wanted to use an existing utility function that does queries for a given connector and query. The utility function does not currently accept an additional parameter for params. I didn't know that I was trying to do is inferior, so I will try to make the utility compatible with both types of queries rather than just the particular query I'm donig to use string injection

Answer (score 1):

I assume that `conn` is an [sqlite3.Connection](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Connection) or a similar connection object for another database.

Parameterized queries usually know how to convert some builtin values to strings suitable for SQL. In the documentation of [`sqlite3.Cursor.execute()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.Cursor.execute) there's a section for ["Default adapters and converters"](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html#default-adapters-and-converters):

> There are default adapters for the date and datetime types in the datetime module. They will be sent as ISO dates/ISO timestamps to SQLite.

So when you use a parameterized query, `execute()` knows how to convert datetime objects to ISO dates/timestamps which SQLite can understand. When you use string interpolation, you have to convert them yourself, e.g. by using [`datetime.isoformat()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.isoformat).